# How to implement placeholder for treeview in javaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I wanted to show the user a information in the place of treeView, like a placeholder in ListView, in the case of empty treeView

Comment: You could wrap it in a BorderPane and add a listener to the rootProperty to display a label in the center of the border pane if the root is null and display the tree in the center of the border pane if the root is not null. I don't know of a stock method that does the same, as with ListView.

Comment: Its also one of the solution, but i have a class which extends treeView , to have some more features. So i wanted to add this placeholder feature also. Thank you

Comment: I don't know if its possible just extending treeview. You could create a class that extends border pane and has a tree view (or your extension thereof) as a private field with the behavior described above